# Compact SWIFT Reduce closure

Tags: swift, reduce, emoticons, country-codes

In the process of getting a country's flag form emoticons using the ISO country code, I came out with this closure.
Any suggestions to make it more compact with anonymous closure ?

```
    let base : UInt32 = 127397
    let country = "CH"
    let countryFlag = country.unicodeScalars.reduce("") { (var flag, code)  in
    flag.append((UnicodeScalar(base + code.value)))
    return  flag 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting you the short answer, I'll provide detail explanation shortly after:

```
let countryFlag = country.unicodeScalars.reduce("") { $0 + "\(UnicodeScalar(base + $1.value))" }
```

And now the explanation. So firstly, you can skip the line with appending, and directly return it in one sentence:

```
let countryFlag = country.unicodeScalars.reduce("") { (var flag, code)  in
    return  flag + "\(UnicodeScalar(base + code.value))"
}
```

Afterwards you can skip declaring `flag` and `code` variables as they can be inferred as `$0` and `$1`:

```
let countryFlag = country.unicodeScalars.reduce("") {
    return  $0 + "\(UnicodeScalar(base + $1.value))"
}
```

And finally if your closure consists of single return statement you can omit `return` keyword. I prefer moving them on single line for better readability:

```
let countryFlag = country.unicodeScalars.reduce("") { $0 + "\(UnicodeScalar(base + $1.value))" }
```

Comment: I appreciate your time, I was stuck trying to apply append on $0. Thank you

Comment: `append` doesn't return anything(it's declared `void`) - instead it modifies the object. That's why you cannot use it inside return statement. Using binary operator `+` however returns the result of the operation(without modifying objects) and that's why it's okay. If you found my answer helpful you could consider marking it as accepted. Happy swifting ;)